# Get all command history with date and timestamp in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I had an R assignment for my finals, I ended up submitting the wrong file. Now I want prove my professor that I have executed all the code before due date and time.

I need to generate all commands from history and with date and timestamps of when they were executed.

Can someone guide me for this, it would be a great help to me.

Thanks in advance

I tried Ctrl+Shift+P-> History Shown in Context Command